# Flutter APP - How to read emails from user App

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gmail

I am trying to build an app with flutter that asks for the users permission to read their email.

I know that I need to use the Permission Services but the thing is, after the user accepts the email permission, how can I read each email from his inbox? I've been reading the gmail API documentation but I am really lost on how to begin.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Você está no SO pt, sua pergunta deve ser em português.